# Can't find DotSpatial.Geometries.dll

Tags: shapefile, dotspatial

I am trying to follow a simple tutorial on Dotspatial web page "[Sample code that demonstrates how to create a Multi Polygon Feature Set](http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MultypgFSCS&referringTitle=Desktop_SampleCode)" I add the DotSpatial.Data.dll to the project references but I can not find the "DotSpatial.Geometries.dll"!

Can you please let me know where can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

Add reference to `DotSpatial.Topology.dll` and change the usings to

```
using DotSpatial.Data;
using DotSpatial.Topology;
```

Comment: Thank for your comment and this is working but I am getting an error at pg[i] = new Polygon(coord); the error is: The type initializer for 'DotSpatial.Topology.Polygon' threw an exception. Can you please let me know why this is happing?

Comment: @user1106951 - did it shown any errors while building? It didn't show any for me..also it ran sucessfully for me generating the shapefiles..i am using VS2010 express..if the error is at runtime, it could be because the randomly generated polygon geometry might have been invalid..